# Remove Pagination: Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I wanted to remove pagination from my wordpress site.

I have used

```
wp_link_pages(array('before' => '<div class="page-links">'.__('Select a page').':&nbsp;', 'after' => '</div>', 'pagelink' => '<span>%</span>'));
```

Please help me removing pagination, currently I am able to view 5 posts only.

If it not the correct code i am looking for, then please route to appropriate one.

Thanks,
Priyank Shrivastava

Comment: Try removing `wp_pagenavi();` from your theme pages.

Comment: add css to class "page-links" {display:none; }

Comment: @priyajain - display none will not solve the Op's problem. As by this it will keep showing just 5 post & user will not able to see other posts.